# Quick Method to install DevCon.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line-tool, devcon

As [refered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to by Microsoft:

> DevCon (Devcon.exe) is included when you install the WDK, Visual
>   Studio, and the Windows SDK for desktop apps.

But these programs take **hundreds of MBs**, and I don't need the full suite installed on my Windows.

Isn't there a **quick way to obtain** just the `devcon.exe` util?

Answers for **any Windows version**, if possible. If not, at least for Windows XP would enough for me.

Comment: For an up-to-date answer and a installer someone created on github, that installs DevCon.exe to your Path env. variable without downloading and installing WDK, see my below post.  This would be ideal if you're deploying to various windows OS's and/or you need to programmatically disable an intermittently failing device such as a USB device and a COM port or both.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

## For Windows XP/Vista + Windows Server 2003 (R2) (as described by Microsoft [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2009/12/16/where-to-find-devcon-exe/)):

**x86:**

Download [Support.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/e/4/6e481b67-54af-4340-a534-25de4229cfc6/support.cab) (which contains the 32-bit Support Tools for [Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326)) and extract `devcon.exe` (download size: 3.45 MB).

**amd64:**

Download [w2k3sp2_3959_usa_x64fre_spcd.iso](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/9/1/8910a383-9e6b-49d2-9953-e52ff65acc5a/w2k3sp2_3959_usa_x64fre_spcd.iso) (which is the [Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, x64 Editions – ISO-9660 CD Image File](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6905)), mount the .ISO, then go to `SUPPORT\TOOLS\SUPPORT.cab` and extract `devcon.exe` (download size: 475 MB).

**x86/amd64:**

Highly recommended due to the size, but it's the oldest version and not hosted by Microsoft anymore. The link is from the Web Archive, and the file has the Microsoft signature so it’s genuine. It was previously available under [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311272/the-devcon-command-line-utility-functions-as-an-alternative-to-device-manager) but now the link is dead.

Download [DevCon v5.2.3718](https://web.archive.org/web/20050322060636/http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/f/11f7dd10-272d-4cd2-896f-9ce67f3e0240/devcon.exe) and run it, enter a path in the “Unzip to Folder" field, then click Unzip to extract (download size: 78 KB).

---

## For Windows 7/8/8.1/10 + Windows Server 2008 (R2)/2012 (R2)/2016:

> **Windows 10 version 1809 (a.k.a. Windows 10 October 2018 Update)**
>
> **Windows Build: 10.0.17763**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 10.0.17763**

**x86:**

Download [82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/0/140EBDB7-F631-4191-9DC0-31C8ECB8A11F/wdk/Installers/82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 6.06 MB).

**amd64:**

Download [787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/0/140EBDB7-F631-4191-9DC0-31C8ECB8A11F/wdk/Installers/787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 6.12 MB).

> **Windows 10 version 1803 (a.k.a. Windows 10 April 2018 Update)**
>
> **Windows Build: 10.0.17134**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 10.0.17134**

**x86:**

Download [82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/5/8/B58D625D-17D6-47A8-B3D3-668670B6D1EB/wdk/Installers/82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.07 MB).

**amd64:**

Download [787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/5/8/B58D625D-17D6-47A8-B3D3-668670B6D1EB/wdk/Installers/787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.53 MB).

> **Windows 10 version 1709 (a.k.a. Windows 10 Fall Creators Update)**
>
> **Windows Build: 10.0.16299**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 10.0.16299**

**x86:**

Download [82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/D/D/7DD48DE6-8BDA-47C0-854A-539A800FAA90/wdk/Installers/82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.09 MB).

**amd64:**

Download [787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/D/D/7DD48DE6-8BDA-47C0-854A-539A800FAA90/wdk/Installers/787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.53 MB).

> **Windows 10 version 1703 (a.k.a. Windows 10 Creators Update)**
>
> **Windows Build: 10.0.15063**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 10.0.15063**

**x86:**

Download [82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/0/4E07EAAD-E394-4EA8-B2B8-D46E46A409C5/wdk/Installers/82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.88 MB).

**amd64:**

Download [787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/0/4E07EAAD-E394-4EA8-B2B8-D46E46A409C5/wdk/Installers/787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.45 MB).

> **Windows 10 version 1607 (a.k.a. Windows 10 Anniversary Update)**
>
> **Windows Build: 10.0.14393**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 10.1.14393**

**x86:**

Download [82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/6/816FE939-15C7-4185-9767-42ED05524A95/wdk/Installers/82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.73 MB).

**amd64:**

Download [787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/6/816FE939-15C7-4185-9767-42ED05524A95/wdk/Installers/787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.29 MB).

> **Windows 10 version 1511 (a.k.a. Windows 10 November Update)**
>
> **Windows Build: 10.0.10586**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 10.1.10586**

**x86:**

Download [82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/E/1/CE19C726-6036-4443-845B-A652B0F48CD7/wdk/Installers/82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 8.65 MB).

**amd64:**

Download [787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/E/1/CE19C726-6036-4443-845B-A652B0F48CD7/wdk/Installers/787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.86 MB).

> **Windows 10 version 1507**
>
> **Windows Build: 10.0.10240**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 10.0.26639**

**x86:**

Download [82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/1/121AA3A0-6E03-4852-B7E6-39C741E1E942/wdk/Installers/82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 8.64 MB).

**amd64:**

Download [787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/1/121AA3A0-6E03-4852-B7E6-39C741E1E942/wdk/Installers/787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.83 MB).

> **Windows 10 Insider Preview**
>
> **Windows Build: 10.0.10075**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 10.0.10075**

**x86:**

Download [82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/B/5/DB538B89-04A0-4D74-AD65-E721D93FFD08/wdk/Installers/82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 8.26 MB).

**amd64:**

Download [787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/B/5/DB538B89-04A0-4D74-AD65-E721D93FFD08/wdk/Installers/787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 7.81 MB).

> **Windows 8.1 Update**
>
> **Windows Build: 6.3.9600.17029**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 8.100.26846**

**x86:**

Download [af0d6547860d8f68c1b0c9da530f699d.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/af0d6547860d8f68c1b0c9da530f699d.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 34.96 KB).

**amd64:**

Download [09844d1815314132979ed88093f49c6f.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/Installers/09844d1815314132979ed88093f49c6f.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 36.63 KB).

> **Windows 8.1**
>
> **Windows Build: 6.3.9600.16384**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 8.100.25984**

**x86:**

Download [af0d6547860d8f68c1b0c9da530f699d.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/9/86925F0F-D57A-4BA4-8278-861B6876D78E/wdk/Installers/af0d6547860d8f68c1b0c9da530f699d.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 34.98 KB).

**amd64:**

Download [09844d1815314132979ed88093f49c6f.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/9/86925F0F-D57A-4BA4-8278-861B6876D78E/wdk/Installers/09844d1815314132979ed88093f49c6f.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 36.66 KB).

> **Windows 8**
>
> **Windows Build: 6.2.9200.16384**
>
> **Driver Kit Build: 8.59.29757**

**x86:**

Download [af0d6547860d8f68c1b0c9da530f699d.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/C/24CA7FB3-FF2E-4DB5-BA52-62A4399A4601/wdk/Installers/af0d6547860d8f68c1b0c9da530f699d.cab), extract the file `fil5a9177f816435063f779ebbbd2c1a1d2` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 33.60 KB).

**amd64:**

Download [09844d1815314132979ed88093f49c6f.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/C/24CA7FB3-FF2E-4DB5-BA52-62A4399A4601/wdk/Installers/09844d1815314132979ed88093f49c6f.cab), extract the file `filbad6e2cce5ebc45a401e19c613d0a28f` and rename it to `devcon.exe` (download size: 35.45 KB).

---

**Note**: If the process of finding and renaming the files is confusing, [download this tiny script](https://mega.nz/#!sPxlWJ6L!icExoQCZW1w7wG43zm_WKfvVJr7xwaNqECXW_S29QfQ) I wrote, put it to the same directory as the downloaded .CAB file(s) and run it to extract and rename the DevCon .EXE files for you (no administrative privileges required). It creates a folder called DevCon in the same directory which includes the versions you downloaded (32-bit/64-bit or both).

All the links (except for the script and DevCon v5.2.3718) are provided by Microsoft, and all links to the .CAB files are the same links that WDK uses to obtain its packages.

Comment: Which one is the link for Windows 7?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez all versions of Windows 8 must work, but Windows 8.1 Update is recommended.

Comment: Very nice! How were you able to find the cab urls?

Comment: Windows 10 version 1809
Windows Build: 10.0.17763
Driver Kit Build: 10.0.17763
x86:
[82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/0/140EBDB7-F631-4191-9DC0-31C8ECB8A11F/wdk/Installers/82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab)
amd64:
[787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/0/140EBDB7-F631-4191-9DC0-31C8ECB8A11F/wdk/Installers/787bee96dbd26371076b37b13c405890.cab)
Please merge :)

Comment: Doesn't work for Build 1903

Comment: Is there a version available for version 1903?

Comment: Do versions of `devcon.exe` from newer Windows 10 builds are backwards compatible with older builds of Windows 10?  E.g., does `devcon.exe` from build 1903 will work on build 1809?  Will `devcon.exe` from (soon to be released) build 1909 work on build 1903 and 1809?  Or do I have to use different builds of `devcon.exe` on each different build of Windows 10, or I can just use the latest `devcon.exe` on all older builds?

Comment: I wish this could be updated (thanks no matter what :) Meanwhile, I googled and found a blog post where newer `devcon.exe` direct download links (e.g. 1903 and 2004) are available in the visitor comment section: https://networchestration.wordpress.com/2016/07/11/how-to-obtain-device-console-utility-devcon-exe-without-downloading-and-installing-the-entire-windows-driver-kit-100-working-method/

Comment: Where can I get version 20h2?

Comment: https://github.com/Drawbackz/DevCon-Installer/blob/master/devcon_sources.json

Update to Windows 11 Insider Preview

Comment: Extremely helpful!

Answer (score 8):

Version 5.2.x of devcon.exe used to be available for download as part of KB article Q311272. MS "retired" that article since, and the old link now redirects to the one you posted.

However, you can still find Q311272 archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20150219111411/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272? and even the download link works. The devcon.exe you get from there is actually a self-extracting ZIP file, contains both 32b and 64b devcon.exe v5.2.3718.0, and should work fine with XP.

Comment: Indeed, it is working for now. Due to its small size download, this is a great solution as long as Micro$oft doesn't remove the link. Thanks you, @DXIV, and good job researching.

Answer (score 5):

### Automatic DevCon.exe Installer (without installing WDK)

In my googling around for this issue, I found something new:

https://github.com/Drawbackz/DevCon-Installer

Check the right side bar under "Releases".  It lets you install `devcon.exe` without installing the whole WDK, so this solution is ideal for people deploying to user's machines that aren't used for Windows driver development.

That long answer above needs updating with the latest version, so is irrelevant by now except if you're using an non-updated Windows version.

I guess if you need to programmatically reset a USB device for instance (my use case), you can include this installer as part of your install process.

### Important Note

Download the latest installer from releases and run it.  Select your architecture (x64 or x86) and click **Update Sources**.  The dropdown box at the top will then be updated.  Right click on "My Computer" from Windows file manager and go to *Properties*.   Check your version of Windows 10, because mine is **21H2 (which the installer calls Windows 11)**, so just be aware of that, so I think 21H2 (Windows 11) is the one to install for me, even though I'm using Windows 10 officially.  See the below screenshot:

[image: My system properties and the DevCon installer side-by-side.]

What's neat about this installer is that it also **automaticaly adds DevCon.exe's location to your Path** environment variable, and all you have to do is check that box! :)

Answer (score 2):

Head to the official ["Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples" repository on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/97cf8edcaddff4fdbc5cc48d56b7d7eb2c39b749/setup/devcon), get the source code, and then compile it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For 32 bits version, browse the Windows Server 2003 CD to:

```
\SUPPORT\TOOLS
```

open the file `SUPPORT.CAB` with some package browser like WinRAR or [Total Commander](https://superuser.com/a/747625/268923) and you will find `devcon.exe` there.
No installation needed to perform.