# Select GPU to use by specific applications

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

I have 2 GFX cards installed: GeForce GTX 1060 and Radeon HD 6670. Both are working fine as I plugged in different monitors to different cards to be sure about it.

I want to force some applications to use Radeon HD 6670 instead of GeForce GTX 1060, but I can't find a way to do it. I've found that in Windows 10 you can switch GPU for applications in Graphics Settings between Power Saving and High Performance, but both options are using GeForce GTX 1060 for me.

Is there other way to select GPU for specific applications, or an option to change Power Saving GPU?

Comment: Microsoft is testing a feature implementation for this in insider build 20190. See https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/08/12/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20190/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Windows 10 GPU switcher only works on laptops that have both Intel iGPU and discrete graphics. On desktops, each card runs its own output port. There no way for one card to send its output to the other card (right now there's only SLI and CrossFire, but they only work when the two cards is the same)

Comment: But it's working for me already: I have monitors plugged into different cards and I can even have half of the window displayed on 1st monitor and half on 2nd monitor (rendered by 1 GFX card displayed by other), it ever works for 3D applications, not only "basic". So 2 GFX card can send data between themselves w/o any problems.

Comment: I just read a post on TH and apparently I was wrong, sorry for that. But you still cannot use Windows 10 switcher. You need to set the monitor that's connected to the card you want to be the primary monitor. You can read this for more information: https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/717383-2-different-graphics-cards-in-1-pc/

Comment: Man, thanks a lot! I've spend the whole day searching how to do in yesterday with no luck. I even contacted Microsoft Support and they didn't know how to do it too. Switching main display in Windows Settings made a trick with NVidia+AMD configuration too :D

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but basically:

As stated above by [Kurumi Gaming](https://superuser.com/users/911862/kurumi-gaming), the Windows 10 Graphics settings does not seem to let you force it to use a secondary non-integrated GPU.

Unfortunetly, the same is true for the "Add Run with graphics processor to start menu" option suggested by ytpillai.

However, there are a few workarounds

## 1. Program Based

Some programs such as OBS that let you choose which GPU to use for certain tasks such as encoding.

## 2. Batch Programs

[Kernel Kue](https://linustechtips.com/main/profile/546462-kernel-kue/) on the LTT Forums found a workaround for Chrome that disables your primary gpu, launches whatever program you want, then enables the primary again. **It requires devcon.exe that comes with Visual Studio** [although you can download it by itself too](https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe). I did that and [this exe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3xF30E-vRHeFX5U5DpdZ312P0cGDj2-/view?usp=sharing) works for me. It's a bit clunky, and the batch file requires you to know the Device instance path for your card. you can get this by going into Device Manager, R-Click your GPU > Properties > Details > (Drop Down) > Device Instance Path. Here is Kernel Kue's Original Script:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64\devcon.exe" disable "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_17C8*"
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
timeout 5
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64\devcon.exe" enable "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_17C8*"
```

#### Better Version that walks you through

I made my own modified version that walks your through it and makes things a bit easier. It's also open source batch (as all batch is).

You can run it directly and drag-and-drop or type a path to an exe you want to run on your secondary gpu, **or** you can call it like this: `RunAsGpu.bat "C:\path\to\file\.exe" parameters`

I only just made it so I'll add bug fixes and a readme later, and if anyone wants to help me add AMD support let me know.

#### https://github.com/ITCMD/RunAsGpu

## 3. Switch GPUs

You can also set your secondary GPU as your primary. This will allow you to set your games to use your second GPU, or, if they don't support that, the above program will let you do that too (just select the opposate graphics card). To change which card is your primary, you'll need to have a display plugged into both cards, then open the Nvidia control panel. I believe in "set up multiple displays" there should be that option. I don't have more than one display atm so I'm not sure.

Comment: Your answer came later, but I'd say this is the most informative of all the answers on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search on Google gave me [this](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/force-app-to-use-dedicated-gpu-windows/). You need to use the programs for Nvidia and AMD to force an exe or other executable to use a specific GPU.

Nvidia is simple enough, just go to the Nvidia Control Panel and enable "Add Run with graphics processor to start menu" in the desktop menu bar.

AMD is a bit more complex but it's still just clicking around. You can find the settings on the AMD Catalyst Control Center.

Details on how to do this stuff are in the link above, please Google before you ask a question on here.

Comment: I've found it too when searching for the solution, and I knew about it a long time ago: it's completely different scenario with integrated + dedicated GPU configuration, and you can do the same by switching between Power Saving and High Performance GPU in Windows 10 Graphics Settings that I've mentioned. I want to switch between 2 dedicated GFX cards not between dedicated and integrated.


So please answer for asked questions next time, not something completely different.

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood. I became the very thing I despise. Sorry bro, ill try to find an answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope you're better at googling than me: I've spend something like 2 hours doing it with no luck, so it's not something so obvious.