# Are the GTX 760 and GTX 1060 mini compatible?

Tags: windows-7, gpu, compatibility

I've built multi-card rigs before, but never with two different GPUs. So I would like to know if the GTX 760 and GTX 1060 mini are compatible on Windows 7, Asrock Extreme4 990FX mobo.

I know that only cards using the same driver are compatible on Windows 7, but I am asking just in case.

Also, if they are compatible, how do they actually work together, i.e. do they work separately from each other and only apply to the output monitor or do they bundle?

Comment: I've already answer this: https://superuser.com/questions/1331645/select-gpu-to-use-by-specific-applications/1331650#1331650

Comment: SLI cards must be the exact same. You can't use to totally different cards, and connect them with an SLI bridge.

Comment: He asks how the two card works if they're attached in one PC, not if he can SLI them. Now with DX12's Explicit Multi-GPU, even an NVIDIA card can work together with an AMD card, it's all up to the developer whether to include the support. And don't forget you can still choose what GPU will be used by the program.

Comment: Hardware-wise, they should work fine.  Drivers are where you're likely to run into issues.  NVIDIA has a questionable track record with GPU support from version to version (higher version don't always work as well as lower ones on any given GPU).  I'm also not even sure if the GeForce 700 series is still officially supported in current drivers either.

Comment: hey, thank you so much, you actually gave me some extra stuff to check before going ahead, well it would have only been a physx booster anyways, so its not a terribly great loss if they dont work together. cheers :)