# How to watch devcon output and save it to a file

Tags: windows, devcon

I installed `devcon` utility like described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe). Now I run it with `C:\devc>devcon.exe find *` and have two issues:

1. Console window close immediately after execution and I don't have time there is nothing to see. How to suspend it?
2. How to redirect its output to a file? I try do it with `C:\devc>devcon.exe find * > file.txt` but created file.txt is empty after execution the command.

OS win10

Comment: Do you call these commands inside a batch or do you type it inside a command window ?
With the last version it works for me.