# Why is my Wi-Fi card permanently disabled after I wake my PC from sleep?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, pci-express, wifi-driver

I have been having this problem for months, where if my PC goes to sleep and I wake it back up, the WiFi card is disabled and I cannot enable it on the "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" page (right-clicking -> press enable doesn't work). The only way to re-enable it is to restart Windows.

PC Specs (that I think are important):

- MoBo: TUF-GAMING-B550-PLUS (nonwifi)
- WiFi Card (In the PCIe slot): ASUS PCE-AC55BT B1 AC1200 Wireless Bluetooth 4.2 PCIe/Mpcie Adapter
- Running Windows 10 21H2

Things I already tried:

- Ran the network troubleshooter (didn't work)
- Ran SFC and DISM (didn't fix it)
- Switched WiFi cards (same problem)
- Switched PCIe slots (didn't work)
- Installed intel wifi drivers (didn't work)
- Installed the drivers from the ASUS website (didn't work)
- Reinstalling Windows 10 (Still had the issue)
- Unchecking the box in Device Manager: "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" (The card errored out in device manager, and I was forced to restart the PC in order to re-enable it.)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As to *why* this happens, it seems to have occurred for many users after a routine Windows update. However, there's are two ways to work around this that restarts WiFi (at least on one PC I have), *without having to reboot*: either stop the *WLAN Autoconfig* Service (wlansvc), then restart it, or **disable the modem** and re-enable it (which I find is more reliable, though more involved). You can stop and start the service from *services.msc*, or disable and enable the wireless hardware from *Device Manager*, here are scripts to make it faster.

- **To stop and restart WLAN Autoconfig Service**

  - Open a text editor such as *Notepad*.
  - Copy the following two lines and paste into the editor.
    `net stop wlansvc`

    `net start wlansvc`
  - Save the file with a *.bat* extension, e.g., *Reset-WLAN.bat* .
  - Make a shortcut to the .bat file, and set it's *Advanced* properties to *Run as administrator*.
- **To disable, then re-enable the wireless card:**

  - Download [Windows Device Console (Devcon.exe)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon) from Microsoft, if you do not have it already. This is the command-line tool needed to turn the modem on or off. It is a file in the [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) for your PC's OS. There are more tips on downloading the correct version at [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/182.how-to-obtain-the-current-version-of-device-console-utility-devcon-exe.aspx) and direct links [**Superuser**](https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe) [kudos to @NetwOrchestration for that answer!].
  - Find the [instance ID for your wireless card](https://wlanbook.wordpress.com/2007/11/10/enable-disable-wireless-card-command-line/). Though you can list all devices using *devcon.exe*, I find it easier to use *Device Manager*:
    [image: Using Device Manager to find hardware ID]

    - Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type *device man*.
    - Select *Device Manager*.
    - Locate the wireless network adapter in the list, right-click on it, and select *Properties*.
    - On the *Properties* dialog, select *Details* tab.
    - From the *Property* drop-down list, select *Hardware Ids*. There are multiple ID's, but I found the first ID in the list, *PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0887&SUBSYS_40628086&REV_C4* for this PC, worked. You might need to try others on your own list, though.
    - Create a .bat script, as above, with the following text (where "[card ID]" is replaced with the ID found above, surrounded with double-quotes), and save it in the same folder with *devcon.exe*:

      `rem Disable and re-enable WiFi modem`

      `devcon.exe disable "[card ID]" timeout /t 3`

      `devcon.exe enable "[card ID]"`
    - Make a shortcut to the .bat file, and set it's *Advanced* properties to *Run as administrator*.

Now, in either case, there are just two quick steps:

- Click on the link.
- Accept the UAC prompt to run as administrator.

In about five seconds, WLAN (and WiFi) should be working. Sorry, I don't know a simple way to bypass the UAC prompt.

Comment: I could use task scheduler to run these commands every time I wake my computer from sleep. Also, the problem is not happening anymore for some reason, but I'll give this a try when I encounter it again.

Comment: @nickylego10, as you say, it's sporadic. No problem for a week or two, then  three or four times in a row, after Hibernate, no WiFi... and sometimes, it will connect on its own after a minute!

Comment: Just encountered the issue, and sadly, the wlansvc reset thing didn't work. I still was not able to re-enable my WiFi card.

Comment: @nickylego10, note the rather large change to the work-around I've added. The second, using *devcon.exe*, is much more reliable at getting WiFi to work. It's a nuisance to need it, but it's the only fix I've found that *works*. Please let me know if that helps!

Comment: What about PnPUtil? Devcon requires me to install Visual Studio Community.

Comment: @nickylego10, see the link I've added above, https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe, for downloading the CAB file, extracting one file, and renaming it to *devcon.exe*. MS does *not* make this easy!

Comment: I tried it, and it forced me to restart my PC in order to re-enable the card. That's also what happened when I used Device Manager

Answer (score 0):

You can also [fix WiFi disconnecting after Sleep in Windows 11/10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wifi-gets-disconnected-after-sleep) through the powershell.

1. right-click on your Desktop and select New -> Shortcut. In the Create Shortcut window, paste the command `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe restart-netadapter -InterfaceDescription '<WIRELESS ADAPTER NAME HERE>' -Confirm:$false`
2. Change the drive C: and wireless adapter names in the code to your own, you can find that information in your device manager.
3. Click Next. In the new window, you can rename the shortcut to WI-FI Reset, and click finish.
4. right-click the shortcut you just created and select Properties. Click Advanced, and in the Advanced Properties window, check option Run as administrator.
5. Next click on OK and Apply, and close the window.
6. Double click on the shortcut, let the system execute the command, and reboot the machine. This should fix your problem.
   You can always read this [guide](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wifi-gets-disconnected-after-sleep) for more solutions to this problem.

Comment: This looks good, but I don't think the article highlights the problem I am having.